# Get colour of specific pixel in an OpenGL texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to get the colour of a specific pixel from a specific texture using OpenGL (C++). I've been looking at [`glGetTexImage()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) since it looks somewhat like what I want, but I can't figure out the context in which I should put it. Am I wrong? It doesn't need to be the fastest option since it's not a frame-by-frame thing; just when the game starts up.

The texture isn't going to be rendered to the screen and is just used as a way to get information. I use the following function to load the texture.

```
GLuint TextureUtil::loadTexture(const char* filename, int* widthVar, int* heightVar) {
        unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename, widthVar, heightVar, NULL, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);

        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


        if (image) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, *widthVar, *heightVar, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        } else {
            std::cout << "ERROR: TextureUtil.cpp - Texture loading failed." << std::endl;
        }

        glActiveTexture(0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        SOIL_free_image_data(image);

        return texture;
    }
```

Comment: Might need to know a little bit more.  Usually you upload the texture with glTexImage2D.  Would it not be more appropriate to read the value there before you upload it to the GPU?  If this is a rendered texture then yes, you'll have to read back the texture contents using glGetTexImage.  What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: You can also consider glReadPixels if your texture is attached to an FBO.

Comment: @Wyck I've edited my question a little bit for context. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: You have `unsigned char *image`.  That's a pointer to the image data.  All the bytes of your pixels are right there.  Do you just need to know how to access the memory to get the RGB for a particular x,y pixel given the raw storage?

Comment: @Wyck I didn't even realize the `unsigned char* image` pointed to the image data, but anything else would be stupid, now that I think about it. Anyway, yeah, I want the RGB values (or, alternatively, a single hex value) for an [x, y] pixel from said image. Do you know how I might do that?

Comment: Looks like you have `GL_UNSINGED_BYTE` with `GL_RGBA`.  So the address of a pixel is `unsigned char* pixel = image + row * width * 4 + column * 4` Then the 4 bytes there `pixel[channel]` ... are in RGBA channel index order. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Wyck I'm afraid not. The address math makes sense, but I don't know how to actually use it in context.

Comment: I have the same problem, but, when I attach my texture to an FBO, I always got black screen. Does anyone have similar problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in a pixel at coordinates column `x` and row `y`, then:

```
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(filename, widthVar, heightVar, NULL, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
int width = *widthVar;

unsigned char* pixel = image + y * width * 4 + x * 4;

unsigned char red = pixel[0];
unsigned char green = pixel[1];
unsigned char blue = pixel[2];
unsigned char alpha = pixel[3];
```

Error checking of the SOIL_load_image function is left for to you to add.  I would fully expect it to return nullptr if the filename didn't exist, for example.

Comment: ...and obviously in real-world code I would either write this into a getPixel function or do something more optimal based on what else might need to be done with the image.

Comment: I can barely believe I couldn't figure this out myself. It's super simple. Anyway, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was clearly making it way too complicated for myself. Thanks again for the help.